# Show that $Df(x_0) = \vec0$ when function converges

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ a $C^1$ function such that $$\lim_{\lVert x \rVert \to + \infty} f(x) = 0$$ Show that there exists an $x_0 \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $Df(x_0) = \vec0$.

I wanted to use the mean value theorem because I feel like there exists two points $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ and by the MVT I would get the point $x_0$ I am looking for but I struggle to find them/show they exist.

I began a quick sketch of a possible proof I thought of :
Let $x_1=(x,0,\cdots,0) \in \mathbb R^n$ and $x_2=(-x,0,\cdots,0) \in \mathbb R^n$. When $x \to +\infty$, $\lVert x_1 \rVert$ and $\lVert x_2 \rVert$ both $\to + \infty$. Now we consider the function $g(t)=f(x_2 + t(x_1 − x_2))$ with $t \in [0,1]$. Then I wanted to use the MVT but I do not know how to use it the proper way to find the result I need. How can I figure this out ?

Comment: What is your definition of $D$?

Comment: @user58697 D is the derivative, the Jacobian matrix.

Comment: I would proceed by showing $f$ is bounded. Then $|f|$ is bounded too. If $|f| = 0$, we have ended. If not, it has a supremum and $\exists a \in \mathbb{R}^n | |f(a)| \geq |f(x)| $ (this is the tricky part to prove). But then $f$ has an extremum at $a$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Define $g(t)=f(x_2+t(x_1-x_2))$ for all real numbers $t$. Check that $g(t) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$ and $g(t) \to 0$ as $t \to -\infty$. If $g'(t)$ is never $0$ the $g$ is strictly monotnic but this contradicts the fact that $g(t) \to 0$ as $|t| \to \infty$. So there exists $t$ such that $g'(t)=0$ and all the partial derivative of $f$ are $0$ at this point.

Comment: I feel like this gives us that ONLY the partial derivative in the $x$ direction is $0$